# How to generate a string by adding the numbers that only contains 0 & 1

Tags: java, string, binary

Given A String(S) as an Input you need to generate the String by adding numbers that only contains 'O' and '1' you need to find the minimum numbers containing only 'O' and '1' that needs to be added to generate String S.

Input: 3401
To generate this number, we need to add these four
numbers: 1101 + 1100 + 1100 + 0100 = 3401
Input
Output
3027
3
3401
4

I tired to solve it by taking input as int and breaking it into binary and then reading it as binary but couldn’t able to do it so

Comment: Add your code please, I think it will be easy for all of us to solve once you do.

Comment: "_numbers containing only 'O' and '1'_" - Does this question confuse the letter `O` with the digit `0`?

Comment: You can take the [tour] and read [ask] for general guidance on how to improve your question, so it's more likely to get helpful answers. For more specific guidance, see [mre] and maybe also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12567365)

Comment: If the answer you give for "3410" is 1101 + 1100 + 1100 + 0100, and the latter 4 numbers are integers whose digits are only 0 (zero) and 1 (one), then it doesn't seem to me that thinking in terms of binary values is right. The only reason to think in terms of binary values is that 100 is strangely formatted as 0100 (purposely to throw you off into thinking about binary values?). Certainly, the binary values of 0b0000_1101, 0b0000_1100, 0b0000_1100, 0b0000_0100 don't add up to 3401 (integer).

Comment: The Input is 3027 & the op is 3 .. and similarly for 3401 .. is 4 but if I’m considering the basic math with each column of ones and zeroes how come 3027 is returning 3 … so if we consider this then … 1011 + 1011 + 1001 ?? how it will ad upto 7 ?? .. or is it being carried forward or ignored ?

Answer (score 0):

First, we create an array containing each digit of the number. To create minimum number of strings, we have to create the largest number. For this, we use every available digit to form a string. If a digit is used,  we append '1' to the string otherwise '0'. Then we decrease the used digits by 1 and decrease the number by the formed number. We repeat this process until the number is 0.

```
Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.next();
        int len = s.length();
        int[] arr = new int[len];
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
        }

        int num = Integer.parseInt(s);
        while(num>0){
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                if(arr[i]>0){
                    temp.append(1);
                } else {
                    temp.append(0);
                }
                arr[i]--;
            }
            System.out.println(temp);
            int var = Integer.parseInt(temp.toString());
            num-=var;
        }
```